# How to edit the formatPrice function in Magento?

Tags: magento

I am using Magento CE 1.9. I want to remove the ".00" point by editing the `formatPrice` function. The template I am editing is `/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml`

How can I trace the location of the `formatPrice` function?

```
$this->getOrder()->formatPrice($this->getItem()->getPrice()
```

I have tried editing `Store.php`, but it does not work.

Comment: maybe you should only `str_replace` the ".00"... The `formatPrice` function is responsible for all price formattings in the entire shop.

Comment: You want to remove ".00" point from through out the site....??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to edit the file Zend\Locale\Data__.xml of you store code (i.e. es.xml)

Edit this lines

```
<currencyFormats>
<currencyFormatLength>
<currencyFormat>
<pattern>#,##0.00 ¤ </pattern>
</currencyFormat>
</currencyFormatLength>
<unitPattern count="other">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
</currencyFormats>
```

Comment: i think it is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html

It is easy to use and does not require special configuration.

To configure the to go **System->Configuration->ET EXTENSIONS->Currency Manager**